# Create a Ribbon Control in Delphi with Combobox as one of the control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, ribbon-control

I am a newbie to using Delphi 2010 to write Ribbon Control...
I wanted a comboBox control with 5 to 6 lines for user to choose from on my ribbon...
I've set the CommandStyle of the TActionClient to csCombobox and I had a hard time figuring out how to set the content of my comboxbox and also the control seem to be disabled once I set the CommandStyle from csButton to csCombobox.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used the Ribbon before, but i made a little test and this is wath i get, I don't know if this is wath you want:

[alt text http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/6885/ribboncombo.png](http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/6885/ribboncombo.png)

Just add strings to the Items property